# Desire 2 Learn LTI - send module name

Tags: desire2learn, lti

Is there a way to have the D2L LMS send to the LTI tool the current module name, or the location of the link in the course table of contents?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there isn't a way for LTI launches to dynamically (at runtime choose a value) provide more contextual information about the launch point other than the originating org unit ID and type.

That said, you can attach custom parameters to LTI Links, so you *could* add a custom parameter to a placed link, with a static value, that the Tool Provider can read (and in such a custom parameter, you could placed deeper contextual information about the link's placement).

The downside to this strategy:

- Custom parameters are attached to External Learning Tool (LTI) links, and not necessarily to their placement, so if you use the same defined link placed in multiple places, you'll get the same custom parameter data
- Custom parameters must be defined statically at link definition time (or modification time), so you must know up front where the link will get used (for your use case), or edit the defined link *after* placement to put in the right information

If all you're talking about is a small number of defined links, then this workaround might be usable; but any kind of volume or wide-scale sharing is going to render this workaround un-useful.